# Find text box in a repeater with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

We have run into the situation where it matters that the max length is turned off on a multiline text box. Having searched everywhere we found lots of examples of workarounds for client side handling. We decided on a simple jQuery extension to handle it. That part was easy, but trying to find the text box in a repeater is proving difficult. I can find the repeater and I tried the following jQuery to go deeper.

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $("[id*=myRPT]").find("[id*=txtComment").maxlength    
    ({ max: 1000});
});
```

I also tried using the .clientid syntax that I could find online and it could never find the control. Is there some secret to actually being able to hit the control with the name changing and nesting that happens in repeaters?

Comment: can you provide a sample fiddle?

Comment: Your `find` selector shown is invalid (missing the closing square-bracket). You also want `.attr('maxlength',1000)` and not the fictional `maxLength` method called at the moment. `maxlength` is a DOM element property and not a jQuery object property.

Comment: Actually maxLength is a jQuery extension method. It was just a matter of finding the text box so it would be legal to call the method on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to find a textbox inside a `Repeater` control is indeed difficult by the nature of the control hierarchy in `ASP.NET`, specially when the parent control implements the `INamingContainer` interface which "overrides" the child controls' ID. However, you can use a few tricks in order to deal with these daunting task. Actually, these tricks makes it quite easy to deal with the issue of finding controls on the client-side.

I guess the easiest one (since you are already using `jQuery`) would be to add a custom data attribute to the textboxes when databinding and then use unobtrusive javascript techniques to find a specific `TextBox`. You can add these attibutes declaratively using databinding expressions...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" data-dataKey='<%# Eval("YourDataKey")'/>
```

notice that the `data-dataKey` will uniquely identify the `TextBox`...make sure your data keys are unique. You can also do it imperatively from code-behind if you intersect the `ItemDataBound` event of the `Repeater` control...

```
protected void Reapeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
{
    if(args.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        TextBox txt = args.Item.FindControl("textbox1") as TextBox;

        if(null != txt)
        {
            txt.Attributes.Add("data-dataKey", yourdatakey);
        }
    }
}
```

I skipped some of the complexities but hopefully you'll get the idea. Then, in your `jQuery` you can select a specific `TextBox` by its data key attribute...

```
function processTextBox(datakey){
    $("input[type=text][data-datakey=" + datakey + "]").maxlength    
    ({ max: 1000});
}
```

Notice that you need to know the data key, but you can tailor your solution to cater for this easily. Let me know if you need further clarifications.

By the way, if what you need is to disable the max length for all textboxes it's just a matter of "tagging" these textboxes with a custom data attribute without any values and use `jQuery` to find the textboxes...

```
$("input[type=text][data-textbox]")
```

or even this "could" work...

```
$("[data-textbox]")
```

Comment: This did put me on the right track. In fact it was just as simple as using the custom created attribute. We actually created a series of them based on the length we wanted and it works like a charm in the repeater.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing my comment, without your HTML this is a bit of guesswork, but try something like this:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $("[id*=myRPT]").find("[id*=txtComment]").attr('maxlength',1000);
});
```

Your selector was missing a closing square bracket and you need to use the jQuery attr method and not the DOM maxLength property.

So long as your generated names id contains `myRpt` and `txtComment`, the *contains* (*=) selectors you are using should work.

**Note: it would help a lot if you published a copy of your HTML output of the page :)**

A better alternative (as mentioned by others) is to add a specific class to the edit boxes and apply the change to those using a class selector.

Comment: Heh, I strongly agree - the HTML output (or even the relevant ASP.NET markup) would be helpful to here.

Comment: Wish I could have posted more, but we are not allowed to post anything real over security concerns that someone could "hack" into our code if they knew what we were doing. Stupid but that really is the rule.

Comment: By the way nice catch on the missing bracket. Typed that on my cellphone.